# Queue.Poll() is return null but Queue.size() >0 in java queue

Tags: java, null, queue

My code:

```
while( Memo.qRcv.size() > 0) {
    MessageReceived msg=Memo.qRcv.poll();
    ...
}
```

Then I got

```
2014-03-01 11:09:36 DEBUG [Thread-16] (threadQueueSendtoUser.java:163) - Memo.qRcv = null, size = 41590
```

Comment: while(Memo.qRcv.size()>0)?

Comment: i mean your loop statement was not correct

Comment: I used some other ways but not better

Comment: Is qRcv a public static member of the Memo class? Has it been set/populated before you run this loop?

Comment: if the queue is empty, poll() will return null but one thing which queue implementation are you using?

Comment: static Queue<MessageReceived> qRcv = new LinkedList<MessageReceived>();

Comment: I make sure it still has not null elements, I have lost many elements. I thought maybe it conflick with function add(), but I already block the Queue want I add() or poll()

Comment: @javaseeker Not correct how? Why all these gnomic pronunciamentos with no content?

Comment: One more things, after Poll() the size() does not decrease

Comment: @EJP  he has changed the statement

Comment: @javaseeker He has corrected an obvious typo. Your question about 'public static member' is answered by the code itself. Your point?

Comment: @LeeTea It is impossible to help you with the little information you have provided so far. What is `Memo`, `Memo.qRcv`? Show the line of code where you log the information (in threadQueueSendtoUser.java line 163). etc. Even better would be to create [a minimal but complete example that reproduces the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that.

Comment: I am finding other way, not use Queue in Java, it not safe for my App

Comment: @assylias My code very simple, I remove the things which no related in my code, normaly is ok but sometimes it happend, My app work with large amount message, that means I want it stable

Comment: @LeeTea (a) there are *many* queue implementations in the JDK and not all of them behave the same way - without saying which you use we can only guess (b) the log statement that prints null / 41590 does not appear in your code -  we don't know where the size number comes from: is it `Mwmo.qRcv.size()`? (c) if `Memo.qRcv` is null, then `Memo.qRcv.size()` will throw an exception, not print 41590 so that does not correspond to the code you have shown. (d) you don't mention if you have more than one thread (e) Bottom line: not enough information in your question.

Comment: @assylias It didn't throw an exception. I use 2 thread, 1 for add() and 1 for poll(). I tried poll() after poll result is null but still NUll and the same size() = 41590

Comment: @LeeTea which queue are you using? Some are thread safe and some are not...

Comment: See my comment above: try to provide a full example that demonstrates the problem. The issue could be due to many different things and you need to show some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution by using ConcurrentLinkedQueue http://www.javacodex.com/Concurrency/ConcurrentLinkedQueue-Example

Problem here is I used 2 thread to process a Queue, should not use normal queue. I will feedback if any problem

Thank you all

Comment: You can use a 'normal queue' as long as you synchronize on it or take some other measure to assure thread-safety.