# How to avoid Multi Thread working on a same object JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, polling

I'm having a problem in my multithreading, with Linked List **poll(), and offer()** returns null, as it already make sure it is not empty with **wait() and notify()**, for more clear I have the similar problem with [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112580/queue-poll-is-return-null-but-queue-size-0-in-java-queue).

**Solution:**

According to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112580/queue-poll-is-return-null-but-queue-size-0-in-java-queue), he solves the problems by:

> Problem here is I used 2 thread to process a Queue, should not use
>   normal queue. I will feedback if any problem

Means that he uses 2 Threads on a same Object, which means **both threads wants to do the jobs** results in **both of them unable to perform as it returns null**. To solve it, you need to have only ONE Thread running or Synchronize?? as said here:

> You can use a 'normal queue' as long as you synchronize on it or take
>   some other measure to assure thread-safety

**My Problem**

I still want to have multiple threads working on a same object, but with synchronize and locks. After done that it still shown the same problems as before **after the lock**.

**Problematic Code**

This code that cause the problem, maybe my implementation of locks are wrong, so it wont work?? I will explain step by step:

```
public void CleanBus(String CleanerName) {
    Bus bus;
    Boolean BusClean = false;
    synchronized (ListBusEngineFix) {
        while (ListBusEngineFix.size() == 0) {
            try {
                ListBusEngineFix.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The code above used to ensure that the List **MUST NOT EMPTY**, if it passed this code means that `ListBusEngineFix` is not empty, and possible to poll after that.

After ensuring that the list not empty, I will try to poll, and store it inside **another list**

```
        bus = (Bus) ((LinkedList<?>) ListBusEngineFix).poll();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
            System.out.println("Cleaners: " + CleanerName + "cleaning " + bus.getBusName());
            BusClean = new Random().nextBoolean();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ((LinkedList<Bus>) ListBusClean).offer(bus);

    }
```

As seen here, I am still inside the synchronize method, I try to poll and **delay for 200ms**, then start to print the value of the value polled.

**The Result**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BusShop.CleanBus(BusShop.java:130)
    at Cleaner.CleanBus(Cleaner.java:25)
    at Cleaner.run(Cleaner.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BusShop.CleanBus(BusShop.java:130)
    at Cleaner.CleanBus(Cleaner.java:25)
    at Cleaner.run(Cleaner.java:13)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As seen the result, we already know **both threads wants to access while it is still in synchronize locks**

**Additional Code**

This are the code that enables the Threads to run the CleanBus Function earlier.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    CleanBus();
}

private void CleanBus() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true) {
        synchronized(this) {
            busShop.CleanBus(CleanerName);
            notify();
        }

    }
}
```

For the Main I create 2 threads as seen below, there are no problem from it.

```
    Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(busShop, "Cleaner 1");
    Cleaner cleaner2 = new Cleaner(busShop, "Cleaner 2");

    Thread thCleaner = new Thread(cleaner);
    Thread thCleaner2 = new Thread(cleaner2);

    thCleaner.start();
    thCleaner2.start();
```

Where is the **notify()** comes from to wake to **wait()**?

```
    //Unshown code are poll offer, so that ListBusEngineFix notify, basically it will not empty.
    if (ListBusEngineFix.size() != 0) {
        synchronized (ListBusEngineFix) {
            ListBusEngineFix.notify();
        }
    }
```

**HINT**

This does not show every time, around 10 tries, there are 2 null exception, sometimes much worse. Cause maybe the other threads is busy, so only one access it, and there is no problem.

Ok, so is there a problem for my synchronize that unable to **lock an object** for one threads only?

Comment: If you're doing this as an exercise, that's fine, but basically `ArrayBlockingQueue` already solves this problem. (EDIT: sorry, it's `ArrayBlockingQueue` that has the `poll()` method.)

Comment: please provide full https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @markspace I realize than `ArrayBlockingQueue` is a List that does not to be synchronize, and it works. The problem is for academic purposes, it needed to be using `synchronize` instead of using easier methods like `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Comment: @markspace so TLDR: Can anyone create a multithread with a working synchronize, cause my suspect would be my synchronize method is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you are always locking on the same object?

Comment: @Joes Lie It's a typical producer-consumer problem, I created a project as demonstration, you can check it out on GitHub, https://github.com/kezhenxu94/blog-code/tree/master/Java-java-lang-Object-wait/src/me/kezhenxu94/blog